# How to create electronically signed PDF in JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Is there a way to sign electronically a PDF generated by JasperServer?

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in the wiki:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/pdf-output-digital-signing-not-implemented-jasperreports

> JasperReports itself does not provide a direct way to sign digital
>   certificates in the PDF report output file nor implements such a
>   feature from iText which is the library used by JasperReports to
>   generate a PDF file.

We would need to customize the iText library (wich is the one used to export de documents).